# Name of Twig variable in a Twig variable

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I get a list of collections right from Doctrine and I store them into an array.
For example:

```
$data['collList'] = $heyDoctrine->giveMeMyColls();
```

But I also want to retrieve some informations about these collections.
I store it into `$data['collectionId']`.
Until this point, everything works fine.
But in my Twig template, I want to create ordered lists with the name of my collection and every item of this list would be an information about this collection.
So, in PHP, I would do this:

```
foreach($data['collList'] as $collItem){
    echo $collItem['name'];
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach($data[$collItem['id']] as $collItemData){
        echo '<li>'.$collItemData.'</li>';
    }
}
```

My problem is: how to do this with Twig?
I don't know how to say to Twig «hey, use «coll.id» as THE NAME of an other variable!
I've looked a bit and I've found the «attribute» function, but I wasn't able to make it work.

How should I do that?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

So, try next twig code:

```
{% for key, collItem in data.collList %}
    {{ collItem.name }}
    <ul>
        {% for collItemData in data[collItem.key] if key == 'id' %}
            <li> {{ collItemData }} </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```